# C++, () operator overloading, what's its job

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, operators

I was reading from a book in C++ and it says:

```
template<class T>
T max(const T& a, const T& b) 
{
    return a>b?a:b;
}

int main() 
{
int n1= 7,n2= 5;
Complex c1(2.0, 1.0), c2(0.0, 1.0);
cout << max(n1, n2) << endl;
cout << max(c1, c2) << endl;
//Compilation Error, can't compile max<complex> since there is no operator >() for complex numebrs.
return 0;
}
```

What does that mean, where did I used the `()` operator for Complex numbers here and what's its job in general? (I don't understand the whole idea behind `()` operator even though I read about it)

Complex is a class with 2 fields one (two doubles) one for real number and one for imaginary number, plus it has > operator

Comment: Hard to answer this question without seeing the definition of `Complex`.

Comment: edited my queestion

Comment: Does your code use `using namespace std;` because there is a std function called `max` and it might be getting confused with your version. Basically need to see all the code, otherwise it's just guesswork,

Comment: @Vlad your answer is right please publish it again, he wrote 'operator >()' not 'operator ()' I misread it!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `Complex` class does not have an `operator >` defined that could be used within the `max()` function to compare two `const Complex` objects.

Check if the `operator >` is declared as a member function, whether the function is declared as a `const` function, or its parameter is a `const` reference.

The operator should be declared either as a member function like this:

```
bool operator >( const Complex & ) const;
```

or, if it is declared as a non-member function (for example as a `friend` function), then it should be declared like this:

```
bool operator >( const Complex &, const Complex & );
```

Comment: it has, read the error message "can't compile max<complex> since there is no operator ()" is says it doesn't have () operator according to the writer

Comment: @clark_smith I think if the operator is declared as a member function then it is not a constant member function.:)

Comment: @clark_smith read the author's comment again more carefully. "*can't compile max<complex> since there is no **operator >()** for complex numebrs*".  It is complaining about a missing `operator >`, not a missing `operator ()`.  There are two very different things. Don't be confused by the `()` following the `>`